# How to convert a selenium webscraping script to exe file?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I've created a script using selenium and chromedriver on pycharm that works absolutely fine. I want to create an exe of that script so that I can run it on other PCs without installing python or the other dependencies. I've tried using pyinstaller but it is not working. Can someone guide me how can I convert that script into exe.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting any error ? as pyinstaller is the best option to turn your script in to executables.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)